# Error after some insertion MongoNetworkError: connection 812 to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed in Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, connection, database-connection

I want to insert around 60 Million data in Mongo DB using a Node js Script so i have create a connection and reuse it like that :

connection.js

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient,
    { mongourl,dbName } = require('../../env');
    let db;
    let mongoobject;

    const option = {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        socketTimeoutMS: 300000,
        poolSize:1000,
        keepAlive: 300000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 300000,
    };

    const connectDb = (callback) => {
        if (db) return callback()
        MongoClient.connect( mongourl, option, 
            (err, database) => {
                if (err) return console.log(err)
                db = database.db(dbName);
                mongoobject = database;
                callback()
            }
        )
    }

    const getDb = () => {
        return db;
    }

    const connectclient = () => {
        return mongoobject;
    }


    module.exports = {
        connectDb,
        getDb,
        connectclient
    }
```

and my insertion function is

```
function saveData(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
      fs.access(dirPath, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
          if (err) {
              console.error(err)
              return
          }
          const startTime = new Date();
          let numlines = 0;
          const fileReference = {}

          fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, filenames) {
              if (err) {
                  console.error("Directory Not Found")
                  return;
              }
              filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
                  const readInterface = new readline(dirPath + filename);
                  let promises = [];
                  fileReference[filename] = 0

                  readInterface.on('line', function (line) {
                      fileReference[filename]++
                      let countcol = line.split('\t').length,
                          productname = line.split("\t"),
                          productsku = line.split("\t"),
                          productprice = line.split("\t");

                      let product_sku, product_name, product_price;

                      if (countcol == 3) {
                          product_sku = productname.splice(0, 2).join("-").toLowerCase();
                          product_name = productsku.splice(0, 2).join(" ");
                          product_price = productprice.splice(-1, 1);

                      } else if (countcol == 4) {
                          let product_sku_ini = productsku.splice(0, 2).join("").toLowerCase(),
                              product_sku_end = productsku.splice(0, 1).join(" ").toLowerCase(),
                              product_name_ini = productname.splice(0, 2).join(""),
                              product_name_end = productname.splice(0, 1).join(" ");

                          product_price = productprice.splice(-1, 1);
                          product_sku = product_sku_ini + "-" + product_sku_end
                          product_name = product_name_ini + " " + product_name_end

                          delete product_sku_ini, product_sku_end, product_name_ini, product_name_end,product_sku,product_name,product_price;

                      }
                      console.info('row start processing ==>>', filename, product_sku, line);
                      delete countcol, productname, productsku, productprice;

                      if (numlines >= 80000) {
                          readInterface.pause();
                          // console.log('promises:', promises)

                          Promise.all(promises)
                              .then(response => {

                                  numlines = 0;
                                  promises = [];
                                  localStorage.setItem(filename, fileReference[filename]);
                                  console.info(`filename Batch Resolved 1 ========>> ${filename}`, localStorage.getItem(filename))
                                  console.log("====================================================== END 1============================================")
                                  readInterface.resume()
                                  // showHeapUses()
                                  // setTimeout(() => process.exit(), 500)
                                  // console.log('resume 1 time:', (new Date().getTime()) - startTime.getTime())
                              })
                              .catch(error => {
                                  console.info(`Error in executing`, error)
                                  numlines = 0;
                                  readInterface.resume()
                                  // console.log('resume 2 time:', (new Date()) - startTime)
                              })
                      }
                      console.log("num line", numlines)
                      numlines++
                      
                      if(product_sku && product_name && product_price) {
                          const memoryUsedMb = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024
                          console.info('the program used', memoryUsedMb, 'MB')
                          async.waterfall([
                              function (callback) {
                                  const checkskuexists = async () => {
                                      let checksamepro = { sku:product_sku };
                                      let check_doc_exist = db.collection(collectionName).findOne(checksamepro);
                                      return check_doc_exist;
                                  }
                                  checkskuexists().then(function(result) {
                                      if(result === null){
                                          callback(true, 'PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND');
                                      }else{
                                          callback(null, result.sku);
                                      }
                                  });
                              },
                              function (sku, callback) {
                                  db.collection(collectionName).updateOne({sku:sku}, {$set:{price:product_price}});
                                  resolve();
                              },
                          ],function (err, result){
                            if (err) {
                                if (err && result == 'PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND') {
                                  prodetails = {name:product_name, sku:product_sku, price:product_price, status:'active'}
                                  db.collection(collectionName).insertOne(prodetails, function(err, res) {
                                    if (err) throw err;
                                    client.close();
                                  });
                                }
                                resolve();
                            }
                          });
                          delete product_sku, product_name, product_price;
                      }else {
                          console.log('product is undefined -- so skiped', line);
                          delete product_sku, product_name, product_price;
                      }

                  });

                  readInterface.on('error', function (error) {
                      delete readInterface, fileReference, promises;
                      console.error("Error in reading file: ", error);
                  });

                  readInterface.on('end', function () {
                      // printPerformance(startTime);
                      localStorage.removeItem(filename);
                      Promise.all(promises)
                          .then(response => {
                              console.info(`filename Batch Resolved 2 ========>> ${filename} -- Completed`)
                              console.log("====================================================== END 2============================================")
                          })
                          .catch(error => {
                              console.info(`Error in executing`, error)
                          })
                      delete readInterface, fileReference, promises;
                  });
              });
          });
      });
    } catch (error) {
        reject("ERROR GOES HERE ", error)
    }
  });
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
MongoNetworkError: connection 812 to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed
        at /var/www/html/reg-dealers-mongodb-script/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:68:15
        at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/reg-dealers-mongodb-script/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:67:20)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
        at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:675:12)
```

This comes after some insertion like 10k or 20k and sometimes some 100k just connection 812 that no. is different and rest error is same so any idea why this is happening and how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your insertion function is too big to follow. But from the error, it is clear that your insertion function is creating a new mongo connection from the pool.

Generally, when a single connection is used to work for a blocking operation other available connections from pool are used to handle the incoming requests that need to use the db. As you have defined 1000 as pool size that's why you are seeing `812 connection closed`.

It is not a wise idea to insert `60 Million data` at once instead divide that in smaller part organize your DB architecture and follow some recommended way to save them(like collection max size, read/write ops, indexing etc). When you need to save multiple documents, you should use the below mongo function:

```
db.collection.insertMany(
   [ <document 1> , <document 2>, ... ],
   {
      writeConcern: <document>,
      ordered: <boolean>
   }
)
```

For more details check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. As, i have used db.collection(collectionName).insertOne(prodetails, function(err, res) {
                                    if (err) throw err;
                                    client.close();
                                  }); so after every insertion i have closed my connection and it will create new connection for every insertion so it is the issue to insert like this way like.
Like i have insert data using read line-by-line so to every insertion it will take one line.

Comment: If I will use insertmany then how to define its batches like example it will insert 100 one time then next 100 and so on.

Comment: Yes, create a batch of some random numbers try saving it to the DB meanwhile you can ready the next batch and follow the same process.